# Extension of lipschitz functions along a curve

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, reference-request, banach-spaces

Given a curve $\gamma$ in a Banach space $X$ and a function f defined along the curve s.t.
$$\big\Vert f(\gamma(t))-f(\gamma(s))\big\Vert\\leq L\big\Vert\gamma(t)-\gamma(s)\big\Vert$$
is it possible to extend the Lipschitz functions to the whole of $X$?

Comment: That depends more on the set of values $f$ can take than on the domain metric space, so you failed to provide the most relevant information here: what is the range space of $f$? 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not always possible to extend when $X$ is a Banach space.  Take a Banach space $Y_n$ which contains an $n$ dimensional subspace $E_n$   such that every projection from $Y_n$ onto $E_n$ has norm at least $C_n$ with $C_n\to \infty$.  ($Y_n$ can e.g. be $L_1$ and $E_n$ the span of $n$ IID gaussian random variables; then $C_n$ is of order $n^{1/2}$.)  Let $X_n = Y_n \oplus_2 E_n$.  For the curve in $Y_n$ take any curve in the  unit sphere of $E_n \oplus \{0\}$ that contains an $\epsilon_n$ net $A_n$ of the unit sphere of $E_n \oplus \{0\}$.  For $f_n$ take the natural isometry from $E_n \oplus \{0\}$ onto $ \{0\} \oplus E_n $ restricted to the curve. Let $F_n$ be an extension of $f_n$ to a Lipschitz mapping on $X_n$; WLOG $F_n$ maps into $ \{0\} \oplus E_n $ since this is a norm one complemented subspace of $X_n$. Let $G_n$ be the positively homogeneous extension of the  restriction  of $F_n$ to the unit sphere of $X_n$. Then the Lipschitz constant of $G_n$ is at most three times the Lipschitz constant of $F_n$. Compose $G_n$ with the obvious isometry from  $ \{0\} \oplus E_n $ onto $E_n \oplus \{0\}$. The restriction of this map to $Y_n$ gives a positively homogenous mapping from $Y_n$ into $E_n$ that is the identity on $A_N$.  By the arguments in
$$
$$
Johnson, William B.(1-OHSN); Lindenstrauss, Joram(IL-HEBR)
Extensions of Lipschitz mappings into a Hilbert space. Conference in modern analysis and probability (New Haven, Conn., 1982), 189–206, 
Contemp. Math., 26, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1984
$$
$$

we conclude that if $\epsilon_n$ is sufficiently small, there is a projection from $Y_n$ onto $E_n$ whose norm is no worse than something like ten times the Lipschitz constant of $G_n$.

All of this shows that you cannot get Lipschitz extensions with controlled norms.  Take an infinite direct sum to get an example where you cannot get any Lipschitz extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a real-valued function $f$, yes, and keeping the same constant $L$, by a simple construction. Check the last mentioned property listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_function#Properties).

Answer (score 0):

The basic extension result for Lipschitz functions is the theorem of Kirszbaum.  This works for functions with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and is expounded in Federer's book on Geometric Measure Theory.  I think that it even works for functions with values in Hilbert space but can't trace a reference.

Comment: Kirszbaum's theorem is for mappings from a subset of a Hilbert space into a Hilbert space.

Comment: And his last name is Kirszbraun.

Comment: @Bill Johnson. Sorry, you are right, of course.   
The theorem I should have quoted was the MacShane-Whitney result that you can extend any Lischitz function from a subset of a metric space retaining the Lipschitz constant, but for the real-valued 
case which I assume, by default, is what the questioner intended.  Sorry about misspelling the name.  Not sure about the etiquette in this forum.  Will this mea culpa suffice or should (can) I edit my response?

hanks again.

Comment: You can edit your answer and this is one of the arch-typical reasons for being able to do so.